# How can I modify a queue collection in a loop?

Tags: c#

I have a scenario where I  need to remove an item for the queue as soon as been processed.
I understand I cannot remove an item from a collection whilst in loop but was wondering if something
could be done with the Enumerator etc...

This is just a basic example throwing an error 
"Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated."

Any suggestions? Thanks a  lot!!!

Code is as follows:

```
     class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {

                Queue<Order> queueList = GetQueueList();

                foreach (Order orderItem in queueList)
                {
                    Save(orderItem);
                    Console.WriteLine("Id :{0} Name {1} ", orderItem.Id, orderItem.Name);
                    queueList.Dequeue();
                }
                Console.Read();

            }

            private static void Save(Order orderItem)
            {
               //we are pretending to save or do something.
            }

            private static Queue<Order>GetQueueList()
            {
                Queue<Order> orderQueue = new Queue<Order>();
                orderQueue.Enqueue(new Order { Id = 1, Name = "Order 1" });
                orderQueue.Enqueue(new Order { Id = 1, Name = "Order 2" });
                orderQueue.Enqueue(new Order { Id = 2, Name = "Order 3" });
                orderQueue.Enqueue(new Order { Id = 3, Name = "Order 4" });
                orderQueue.Enqueue(new Order { Id = 4, Name = "Order 5" });
                return orderQueue;
            }
        }

        public  class Order
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your foreach to:

```
while (queueList.Count > 0)
{
    Order orderItem = queueList.Dequeue();
    Save(orderItem);
    Console.WriteLine("Id :{0} Name {1} ", orderItem.Id, orderItem.Name);
}
```

**Edit:**

To reprocess if save fails do something like:

```
while (queueList.Count > 0)
{
    Order orderItem = queueList.Dequeue();

    if (!Save(orderItem))
    {
        queueList.Enqueue(orderItem); // Reprocess the failed save, probably want more logic to prevent infinite loop
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Successfully saved: {0} Name {1} ", orderItem.Id, orderItem.Name);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

John K mentions thread safety which is a valid concern if you have multiple threads accessing the same `Queue`. See http://ccutilities.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/40529#678487 for a `ThreadSafeQueue` class that covers simple thread safety issues.

---

**Edit: Here's the thread safety example I keep pointing everyone to :-)**

Here's an example of the thread safety issues mentioned. As shown the default `Queue` can "miss" items while still decreasing the count.

**Updated:** To better represent the problem. I never add a null item to the `Queue` but the standard `Queue.Dequeue()` returns several null values. This alone would be fine but in doing so a valid item is removed from the internal collection and the `Count` decreases. It's a safe assumption, in this specific example, that every `null` item returned from a `Queue.Dequeue()` operation represents a valid item that was never processed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace SO_ThreadSafeQueue
{
    class Program
    {
        static int _QueueExceptions;
        static int _QueueNull;
        static int _QueueProcessed;

        static int _ThreadSafeQueueExceptions;
        static int _ThreadSafeQueueNull;
        static int _ThreadSafeQueueProcessed;

        static readonly Queue<Guid?> _Queue = new Queue<Guid?>();
        static readonly ThreadSafeQueue<Guid?> _ThreadSafeQueue = new ThreadSafeQueue<Guid?>();
        static readonly Random _Random = new Random();

        const int Expected = 10000000;

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Creating queues...");

            for (int i = 0; i < Expected; i++)
            {
                Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                _Queue.Enqueue(guid);
                _ThreadSafeQueue.Enqueue(guid);
            }

            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Processing queues...");

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessQueue);
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessThreadSafeQueue);
            }

            int progress = 0;

            while (_Queue.Count > 0 || _ThreadSafeQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);

                switch (progress)
                {
                    case 0:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Processing queues... |");
                            progress = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    case 1:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Processing queues... /");
                            progress = 2;
                            break;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Processing queues... -");
                            progress = 3;
                            break;
                        }
                    case 3:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Processing queues... \\");
                            progress = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                }

                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }

            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished processing queues...");
            Console.WriteLine("\r\nQueue Count:           {0} Processed: {1, " + Expected.ToString().Length + "} Exceptions: {2,4} Null: {3}", _Queue.Count, _QueueProcessed, _QueueExceptions, _QueueNull);
            Console.WriteLine("ThreadSafeQueue Count: {0} Processed: {1, " + Expected.ToString().Length + "} Exceptions: {2,4} Null: {3}", _ThreadSafeQueue.Count, _ThreadSafeQueueProcessed, _ThreadSafeQueueExceptions, _ThreadSafeQueueNull);

            Console.WriteLine("\r\nPress any key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void ProcessQueue(object nothing)
        {
            while (_Queue.Count > 0)
            {
                Guid? currentItem = null;

                try
                {
                    currentItem = _Queue.Dequeue();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _QueueExceptions);
                }

                if (currentItem != null)
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _QueueProcessed);
                }
                else
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _QueueNull);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(_Random.Next(1, 10)); // Simulate different workload times
            }
        }

        static void ProcessThreadSafeQueue(object nothing)
        {
            while (_ThreadSafeQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                Guid? currentItem = null;

                try
                {
                    currentItem = _ThreadSafeQueue.Dequeue();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _ThreadSafeQueueExceptions);
                }

                if (currentItem != null)
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _ThreadSafeQueueProcessed);
                }
                else
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _ThreadSafeQueueNull);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(_Random.Next(1, 10)); // Simulate different workload times
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a thread safe <see cref="Queue{T}"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        public class ThreadSafeQueue<T> : Queue<T>
        {
            #region Private Fields
            private readonly object _LockObject = new object();
            #endregion

            #region Public Properties
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets the number of elements contained in the <see cref="ThreadSafeQueue{T}"/>
            /// </summary>
            public new int Count
            {
                get
                {
                    int returnValue;

                    lock (_LockObject)
                    {
                        returnValue = base.Count;
                    }

                    return returnValue;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Public Methods
            /// <summary>
            /// Removes all objects from the <see cref="ThreadSafeQueue{T}"/>
            /// </summary>
            public new void Clear()
            {
                lock (_LockObject)
                {
                    base.Clear();
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Removes and returns the object at the beggining of the <see cref="ThreadSafeQueue{T}"/>
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public new T Dequeue()
            {
                T returnValue;

                lock (_LockObject)
                {
                    returnValue = base.Dequeue();
                }

                return returnValue;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Adds an object to the end of the <see cref="ThreadSafeQueue{T}"/>
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="item">The object to add to the <see cref="ThreadSafeQueue{T}"/></param>
            public new void Enqueue(T item)
            {
                lock (_LockObject)
                {
                    base.Enqueue(item);
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Set the capacity to the actual number of elements in the <see cref="ThreadSafeQueue{T}"/>, if that number is less than 90 percent of current capactity.
            /// </summary>
            public new void TrimExcess()
            {
                lock (_LockObject)
                {
                    base.TrimExcess();
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi That works.What about if i wanted to dequeue the item only if saving was successfull.Can I still do that? 

sorry + thanks not familiar with queue

Comment: @devnet247: not really. If you don't dequeue the item at the top, you cant get at the one after it.  You need to move the failed item to the _tail_ of the queue like this sample does.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.This will do for now.
I have to implement full threading and this process occurs in a wcf service.Another thing to learn.thanks again

Comment: There is also Queue.Peek which allow you to get the item from queue without dequeuing it. If thing goes right, you can then Dequeue it later.

Comment: @m3rLinEz: Good point. This works good in single threaded applications but I prefer the Dequeue()/Enqueue() on failure pattern so it can be extended to multiple threads w/o concern of two threads processing the same item.

Answer (score 1):

foreach as a reasonable way to iterate through the queue *when you are not removing items*

When you want to remove and process items, the thread-safe, proper way is just remove them
one at a time and process them after they have been removed.

One way is this

```
// the non-thread safe way
//
while (queueList.Count > 0)
{
    Order orderItem = queueList.Dequeue();
    Save(orderItem);
    Console.WriteLine("Id :{0} Name {1} ", orderItem.Id, orderItem.Name);
}
```

It's possible for the number of items in the queue to change between queueList.Count
and queueList.Dequeue(), so to be thread safe, you have to just use Dequeue, but Dequeue will throw when the queue is empty, so you have to use an exception handler.

```
// the thread safe way.
//
while (true)
{
    Order orderItem = NULL;
    try { orderItem = queueList.Dequeue(); } catch { break; }
    if (null != OrderItem)
    {
        Save(orderItem);
        Console.WriteLine("Id :{0} Name {1} ", orderItem.Id, orderItem.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: The try around the catch won't solve the thread safety issue since with many threads hitting the same queue it's possible for Dequeue() to return a null object while actually removing an item from the internal collection. See http://ccutilities.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/40529#678487 for a better option.

Comment: @John: No just experience. I had recently written an application that spawned 100 threads to process files from a single `Queue` and noticed the even though my `Queue.Count` went to zero other "processed" counters didn't add up to the initial `Queue.Count`. The simple locks I added to the `ThreadSafeQueue` provided consistent results no matter how many threads I threw at the same `Queue`

Comment: Thanks for your help guys!!
Will look at that article now

Comment: @Cory: good to know.  I find it remarkable that the .net queue class isn't thread safe but it's clear that they weren't thinking about threads by the fact that dequeue throws then the queue is empty.

Comment: @John: I edited my answer to provide an example of the behavior I was talking about.

Comment: For posterity, .NET 4 introduced the ConcurrentQueue<T> class which solves this out of the box: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you are trying to process the element in queue one-by-one.

How about wrapping this in `while` loop and process each element from Dequeue, until the queue is empty?

Comment: In production code we have a queue of orders to process and after each one of them I need to dequeue them.
Can you show me with a little snippet what you mean?

Thanks